# Set "hbase.server.keyvalue.maxsize" Programmatically via Java

Tags: java, spring-boot, hadoop, hbase

I was performing hbase operations via Java Spring boot. I was getting error **"Cell with size 10762275 exceeds limit of 10485760 bytes"**.

Somewhere I came to know about increasing cell size i.e need to set "hbase.server.keyvalue.maxsize" to required size in hbase-site.xml for this issue to resolve.
I added this property and issue resolved.

However I want to add this property via my Java Code, because I may not have access to hbase-site.xml in the production.

My Configuration method for setting properties is:

```
public Configuration createHbaseConfiguration() {
        Configuration conf = HBaseConfiguration.create();
        conf.clear();
        conf.set("hbase.master.port", hbaseConnectionPortNum);
        conf.set("hbase.master", hbaseConnectionIpAddr);
        conf.set("hbase.zookeeper.quorum", zookeeperConnectionIpAddr);
        conf.set("hbase.zookeeper.property.clientPort", zookeeperConnectionPortNum);
        conf.setInt("hbase.client.retries.number", 2);
        conf.setInt("hbase.client.keyvalue.maxsize", 0);
        conf.setInt("hbase.server.keyvalue.maxsize", 0);
        return conf;
    }
```

I am able to connect to hbase, also I can do all other hbase operations via java with these proeprites, however I am getting same above issue of cell size.

*Note:* setting "hbase.server.keyvalue.maxsize" to 0 removes all restriction of cell size.

**Summarize:** 
*If I set property "hbase.server.keyvalue.maxsize" in hbae-site.xml it is wotking perfectly fine, however If I try to add it programatically via java, it is not working.*

Please let me know cause and solution to the problem?

Answer (score 3):

*hbase.server.keyvalue.maxsize* protect your production server from misbehaved clients which try to upload big cells. This property cannot be overriden by client, this contradicts with it original purpose.

*hbase.client.keyvalue.maxsize* used to validate cell size on client side without request to server. Usually it has same value as *hbase.server.keyvalue.maxsize*.

This is bad idea to upload cell which size exceeds 10MB(default value). Try to read about [MOB](https://hbase.apache.org/book.html#hbase_mob) feature in HBase, it designed for your use case.

Comment: can you post link on documentation, that hbase.server.keyvalue.maxsize is protected from changing from client side?

Answer (score 1):

I doubt, if there is any property named "*hbase.server.keyvalue.maxsize*".
It is "*hbase.client.keyvalue.maxsize*" property which disables the restrication on Keyvalue instance .

Here is the hbase-default.xml : https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/hbase/hbase.apache.org/trunk/hbase-default.xml

Yes, you can set this property in the java program as given below.

```
conf.set("hbase.client.keyvalue.maxsize","0");
```

Comment: Yes, there is porperty with "hbase.server.keyvalue.maxsize". You can check this at https://hbase.apache.org/book.html#config.files or https://github.com/apache/hbase/blob/master/hbase-common/src/main/resources/hbase-default.xml.

Comment: Also I have already set the property that you said, however it still wont work and gives same error

Answer (score 0):

what is the results if we change to 0 for both client and server? will the MOB threshold change to the setting value? i.e. no limit. or what is the bad results?

```
hbase.client.keyvalue.maxsize = 0;
hbase.server.keyvalue.maxsize = 0;
```